# Aplicación Android SocketTimeoutException cuando me conecto a un servidor local

Tags: android, api, kotlin, volley, android-wear

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación android para un dispositivo WearOS 2.0+, usando un TicWatch 3 para probarla. El problema viene cuando intento hacer una petición GET a una API que tengo desplegada en mi ordenador en la IP 192.168.1.132:3000. Cuando el reloj se encuentra únicamente conectado a la red WiFi donde también se encuentra mi ordenador (sin conectarse por Bluetooth al móvil), se obtiene la información correctamente. Sin embargo, cuando activo el Bluetooth en mi móvil e intento realizar lo mismo que lo anterior, me salta este error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.victorrubia.tfg, PID: 5079
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.132 (port 3000) from /192.168.167.239 (port 37933) after 10000ms
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:185)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:129)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:137)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.kt:63)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.kt:295)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:207)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

He intentado hacer una petición GET al dominio google.com a modo de ejemplo y este sí que ha  funcionado estando conectado con el móvil.

Viendo el error, deduzco que el reloj intenta conectarse a la IP 192.168.1.132:3000 desde una subred distinta, 192.168.167.239, sin embargo, no logro entender por qué, ya que mi móvil se encuentra conectado a la misma WIFI que mi ordenador. Según las guías de Android Developers, las peticiones de red del reloj se harán en proxy con el móvil mientras esté conectado a este por Bluetooth.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a resolver cómo conectarme a mi API desde el reloj mientras está conectado por Bluetooth a mi móvil?

Answer (score 0):

La solución puede ser el ClearTraficHttp. Esta funcionalidad fue eliminada a partir de la api 28 de android. Esto quiere decir q para testear con dominios http:// debes hacer configuraciones previas. puedes encontrar una respuesta aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted